# How to determine timer frequency in linux

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I need to write a kernel module to calculate Linux Kernel Timer (Interrupt) Frequency .

somebody told me I need to use a timer in my module but I don't know how to do that clearly :(

My final goal is to write the result (the frequency) in some file ( for example in: /proc/osfreq/ ) .

=)

Comment: The kernel timer interrupt frequency is already defined as `HZ` in `<asm/param.h>`

Comment: I need to log It's real-time value of it in a file

Comment: your goal is not clear to me, do you want to write a module that uses kernel timer or do you want to time how often some interrupt occurs?

Comment: You should not see variation in the number of cycles per time period from that specified, but only jitter which is to say variable interrupt latency.  If you want to make experimental measurements, you will need something to measure against.  Often this is done with a platform-specific reference, for example a CPU cycle counter.  Of course such metrics depend on clock speed and sleep state, so they can only be used in controlled circumstances with full awareness of the system state.

Comment: @Raber I want to write a kernel module, so calculate current kernel timer frequency. Just that

Answer (score 13):

There are many ways to get the cpu's time frequency:

```
1. zcat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_HZ

# CONFIG_HZ_100 is not set
CONFIG_HZ_250=y
# CONFIG_HZ_1000 is not set
CONFIG_HZ=250
```

means 250 Hz

```
2. cat /proc/interrupts |grep LOC; sleep 1;cat /proc/interrupts |grep LOC

LOC:   43986173   44089526   43986113   44089117
LOC:   43986424   44089777   43986364   44089368
```

means there are 4 logic CPUs, whose frequency is:   43986424   -   43986173   ~=250.

Also, you can get value of var cpu_khz in proc.c at kernel space.

Comment: A solution, But not my desire answer.. we knew the frequency really is not constant in some degree.. I need to get current real value with a module.

Comment: I got identical results after 10 sec delay: cat /proc/interrupts  | grep LOC ; sleep 10; cat /proc/interrupts  | grep LOC
LOC:         98        152        121         91   Local timer interrupts
LOC:         98        152        121         91   Local timer interrupts

Comment: Not working for me - I don't have /proc/config.gz and the LOC values between 1s change by far more than 250 (one CPU by ~8k and other  by ~11k). Looks like too far from what I expected.

Comment: Had to modify the command slightly on my ARM9 device running a modified 2.6.21 kernel, using `grep Timer` instead of `grep LOC`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just print the global variable HZ's value in the module 
using printk, and check the kernel log after loading the module using $dmesg, then you can find the value of HZ.